# Error: Cannot find module 'symbol-observable' in Ionic 4

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, node-modules

Tried running ng serve this error keep appearing

```
Error: Cannot find module 'symbol-observable'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js:10:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: do a just `npm install` then start again.

Comment: same issue after trying npm i

Comment: Most probably then you would need to install symbol observable independently `npm i symbol-observable`. But the original issue could be different altogether

Comment: okay will try. thanks

Comment: Did you import symbol-observable by accident?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `npm`

```
npm install --save symbol-observable
```

https://github.com/benlesh/symbol-observable

then import it where you using

```
import Symbol_observable from 'symbol-observable';
```

Comment: if it helps mark as correct for futer users will get it

Comment: how about this Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'? @ORBIT

Comment: @OliverPreciousChukwuemekaJr `npm i rxjs`